# In Java, Strings are immutable, so what exactly happens when do this?

Tags: java, string

```
String s;
/*code*/
s = "foo";
```

Is a whole new object being created, since the empty string can't change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
String s;
```

doesn't create an "empty string", it's simply an uninitialised variable.

This:

```
s = "foo";
```

sets that variable to refer to a `String` object.  It's the object that's immutable, not the variable.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's an uninitialized reference - I'd say it's an uninitialized *variable*. I like to draw the distinction between variables, references, and objects. (The *value* of `s` is a reference after it's been initialized; `s` itself isn't the reference.)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Thanks. I realize I'm extremely pedantic when it comes to this :) See if you find my analogy useful - any suggestions or corrections would be welcomed.

Answer (score 5):

You need to understand the difference between *variables* and *objects*.

Consider this code:

```
String x = "hello";
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    x = x + i;
}
```

This will end up creating 11 string *objects*, but there are only two *variables* involved (`x` and `i`). At any point, the *value* of `i` is an integer (0-10) and the *value* of `x` is a reference to a `String`. (It could be `null` too, but it happens not to be in this example.)

It's important to understand that `x` is not an object, nor is the *value* of `x` an object.

If it helps to think of it in physical terms, consider a piece of paper with my home address on it:

- The piece of paper is like the variable - it's "somewhere a value can be stored".
- The address written on the piece of paper is like the reference - it's a way of *finding* an object
- The house itself is like the object.

Neither the piece of paper nor the address is the house itself. If you rub the address out on the paper and write a different address instead, that doesn't make any changes to my house - just like changing the value of `x` doesn't make any changes to the string objects themselves in my sample code.

Answer (score 2):

`s` isn't currently assigned to anything at all.

But if you had -- if you had defined `String s = "";` and then `s = "foo";`, then the empty string isn't changed, but the variable `s` is changed to *refer* to the string `"foo"` instead of the empty string.

Comment: there is no empty string [it was never created]

Comment: Yes, much better and much more accurate. I'm sorry for being so picky on the details - I believe this point is important for java beginners.